# Entities with namespace not working on Edge and IE

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt, microsoft-edge, xml-namespaces

I have one XML file and its XSL transformation file:

`simple.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="simple.xsl"?>

<!DOCTYPE simple [
  <!ENTITY ie "<expan>id est</expan>">
]>

<text xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
  I am happy &ie; I am not upset.
</text>
```

`simple.xsl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:n="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//n:text" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="n:text">
    <html> 
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="n:expan">
    <span style="color: red;"><xsl:apply-templates /></span>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I open the XML file on Firefox, the span is correctly generated:

[image]

But on Edge and Internet Explorer, the `n:expan` template is not applied, so `id est` is not in a span and not written in red:

[image: Edge]

When I remove the namespace and all the `n:` prefixes, it works well on Edge and IE. Also, when I remove the `ie` entity and write directly `I am happy <expan>id est</expan> I am not upset.` it works on both browsers.

How should I do to make it work with both entities and namespace?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently different processors have different ideas about which namespace the `expan` element belongs to. I see in my own tests that Saxon and Xalan put it in its parent `text`'s namespace, while libxslt thinks it is in no-namespace.

> How should I do to make it work with both entities and namespace?

How about:

```
<xsl:template match="expan | n:expan">
```